# How to join a column with duplicate names in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two tables that I need to join in python. I have multiple columns that have the same  name; however, I want to change the name ADDING A number suffix.

| type | extension |
| --- | --- |
| A | 'url': 'https:table1 |
| D | 'url': 'https:table2 |

| type | extension |
| --- | --- |
| A | 'url': 'https: |
| D | 'url': 'https: |

```
# My current code that gets an error because the join has duplicate names
df1 = (pd.concat({i: pd.DataFrame(x) for i, x in df22.pop('careTeam').items()})
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
        .join(df22)
         .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Error message:columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['type','extension'], dtype='object')

Desired output table:

| type1 | extension1 | type2 | extension2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 'url': 'https:' | A | 'url': 'https:table1 |
| D | 'url': 'https:' | D | 'url': 'https:table2 |

Comment: `pd.concat([df2, df1.add_suffix(2)], axis=1)`?

Comment: Are existing numbers at the end of columns names to be incremented, or should all columns from df2 just have `2` at the end?

Comment: [pandas DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has a parameter `suffixes` that can append a suffix to the column name automatically. What have you tried so far based on your own research and what went wrong with your attempts?